# New Tag Suggestion/ Modification- REST API

Tags: discussion, support, tags

The current tag refers to Salesforce core (Force.com). It might be of value to either modify this, or create a new one for Marketing Cloud.

Comment: Wouldn't you then just tag with both `[rest-api]` and `[marketing-cloud]`?

Comment: Ah I see what you mean... maybe it's being overtly pedantic expecting the tags tags to match description

Comment: Maybe not...I don't have any domain knowledge here. What tag would you actually propose?